# change clear button in TextField

Tags: swift, button, textfield

i need to know if it is possible to change the clear button (put an image) in Text Field (I´m using textfield from Material -> https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)

Now i have an X :
[image]

but i would like to be this way:
[image]

I found some possible code:

```
let customClearButton = UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UITextfield.self])
customClearButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "icon_info"), for: .normal)
```

but it's not working when i put my textfield the error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'TextField?' to expected element type
>   'UIAppearanceContainer.Type'

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `clearIconButton?.image = UIImage(named: "cameraIcon")` for a Material `TextField`